# Mysql set default value if entry does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

When I execute the following query :-

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.last_login,
profile_pictures.pic_resized, profile_pictures.pic_blurred, 
user_profile.date_of_birth,  user_profile.u_country,
matches.total_score AS score,
favorites.id AS is_favorite,
relationships.id AS is_match,
profile_visitors.id AS is_profile_viewer,
block_chat.id AS is_blocked
FROM users
INNER JOIN user_profile ON users.id = user_profile.user_id
LEFT JOIN profile_pictures ON users.id = profile_pictures.user_id
LEFT JOIN match_collections ON users.id = match_collections.user_id AND match_collections.status='valid'
LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.collection_id = match_collections.id AND match_id = 44700
LEFT JOIN favorites ON favorites.subject_id = 11354 AND favorites.object_id = 44700
LEFT JOIN relationships ON relationships.user_id = 11354 AND relationships.friend_id = 44700
LEFT JOIN profile_visitors ON profile_visitors.viewed_id = 11354 AND profile_visitors.viewer_id = 44700
LEFT JOIN block_chat ON block_chat.subject_id = 11354 AND block_chat.object_id = 44700
WHERE users.id = 11354
```

The result appear:[image]
where is_favorite and is_match is null which refer that there are no entry for the user 44700 in those tables.

The question is: How to set a default value like `-1` instead of `NULL`?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this :-

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.last_login,
profile_pictures.pic_resized, profile_pictures.pic_blurred, 
user_profile.date_of_birth,  user_profile.u_country,
matches.total_score AS score,
if(isnull(favorites.id),-1,favorites.id) AS is_favorite,
if(isnull(relationships.id),-1,relationships.id) AS is_match,
profile_visitors.id AS is_profile_viewer,
block_chat.id AS is_blocked
FROM users
INNER JOIN user_profile ON users.id = user_profile.user_id
LEFT JOIN profile_pictures ON users.id = profile_pictures.user_id
LEFT JOIN match_collections ON users.id = match_collections.user_id AND match_collections.status='valid'
LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.collection_id = match_collections.id AND match_id = 44700
LEFT JOIN favorites ON favorites.subject_id = 11354 AND favorites.object_id = 44700
LEFT JOIN relationships ON relationships.user_id = 11354 AND relationships.friend_id = 44700
LEFT JOIN profile_visitors ON profile_visitors.viewed_id = 11354 AND profile_visitors.viewer_id = 44700
LEFT JOIN block_chat ON block_chat.subject_id = 11354 AND block_chat.object_id = 44700
WHERE users.id = 11354
```

You can use the `if(isnull(exp1),exp2,exp3)` wherever you need to tackle `nulls`

Comment: BTW, it's not `isnull` rather `ifnull`. `isnull` is present in MSSQL.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return something other than NULL, if that's what is in the field use a CASE statement to overide what is returned.

```
case when favorites.id is NULL then '-1' else favorites.id end as is_favorite
```

Comment: you are not handling the case when its not null.

Comment: You're right.
case when favorites.id is NULL then '-1' else favorites.id end as is_favorite.
That correction would do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `COALESCE` or `IFNULL` in mysql to avoid this situation like

```
COALESCE(favorites.id,-1) AS is_favorite
```

OR

```
IFNULL(favorites.id,-1) AS is_favorite
```

Answer (score 0):

[`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) should do the job : `..., IFNULL(favorites.id,-1) as is_favorite, ...`

Comment: IFNULL does not worked,is_null as "BhupeshC" answered worked fine

Comment: @Moussawi7: quite strange; it seems to me it should work... anyway, it's not so important since you got the solution that works for you already.

Comment: Moreover, it can't be. if `IFNULL` is not working for him then it's not MySQL at all.